# How to edit navbar from bootstrap templates and convert it into dropdown with same design?

Tags: java, php, css, dropdown

How to edit navbar from bootstrap templates and convert it into dropdown with same design? I want it like when I hover on the word that it will show the same color as the background color of the navbar

```
 <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

This is the part that I want to convert into a dropdown with same design. I don't need the page-scroll on this part and the href coz I want the things in the dropdown to have the href. What do I need to do?

```
   <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Log In</a></li>
```

Comment: Try specifying the class "dropdown" to your li element: 
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Log In</a></li>

Then <ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>

Comment: I don't need the page-scroll on the part that I want to make a dropdown. What do I need to do? @HaroldScholtz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement by implementing data-toggle dropdown

```
 <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="line-height:2.428571;">
              Log in
              <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
           <li><a href="about-gbg.html">About GBG</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
</li>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/ez2tacju/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I do it:

```
<li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right dropdown">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    Text
</a>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="???">
            Text
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It might also be the page-scroll class that makes the buttons look like it does

Comment: The design is different when I try this, It's wrapped around a blue bubble. Is it possible to make it the same design?

Comment: You will need to style it or add the design class to the element

Comment: I'm very noob with design T_T. Can you explain it more please? @harold scholtz

Comment: You will need to check which class gives you the blue bubble you are referring to. I think it might be these: nav navbar-nav navbar-right

I will edit my answer and include these for you to test out